# A problem with the CTkImage method in Customtkinter

Tags: python, customtkinter

```
self.one = customtkinter.CTkImage(Image.open(r"hangman_drawings/un.png"),size=(3,3))
self.main_title.configure(text='',image=self.one)
```

I got a problem with my code. I am importing images with `CTk` image in my class App and then I load them in a method. When I run my whole code this error appears :

```
UserWarning: CTkLabel Warning: Given image is not CTkImage but <class 'str'>. Image can not be scaled on HighDPI displays, use CTkImage instead.

  warnings.warn(f"{type(self).__name__} Warning: Given image is not CTkImage but {type(image)}. Image can not be scaled on HighDPI displays, use CTkImage instead.\n")
```

I have searched answers on other posts but everyone was doing the same thing that I put in my code, and still got the error. I'm pretty much a beginner in Python. Sorry, if this isn't really clear.